# How to override onPaste in Formik input and change pasted text?

Tags: reactjs, clipboard, formik

How do I override onPaste on a Formik input? I need to convert pasted text to upper case and then paste it into the input. I found something similar in plain JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event but I have no idea how to convert it to Formik API.

Comment: `onChange` doesn't work?

Comment: Show us the code you done so far

Comment: @demkovych how should that work?

Comment: onChange should fired when input value changed. When you past something - input value changed.

Comment: how does that solve the problem with changing the case of pasted text?